# Win 32, script, process all files in directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I need to process all txt file in some folder using a console application. The command looks similar to this:

```
convert input_file.txt -par1 -par2 -par3
```

How to write a batch processing all files in the folder, passing file name as parameter to console apllication? Another idea, what about a Python solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `for`

```
for %f in (*.txt) do @convert "%f" -par1 -par2 -par3
```

Note that I use `@` to suppress echoing of the command line at each iteration of the for loop.  This is optional.

The above syntax is appropriate for use at the interactive console. When executing in a batch file, the `%f` must be replaced with `%%f`.